# Why Angular (5) HostListener event works in Chrome but not IE?

Tags: angular, cross-browser

I have a "popover"/help text directive that is working in Chrome and IE11.  The immediate problem is that IE does not seem to fire the mouseenter event that causes the help text to become visible.  The debugger line in that function is never reached in IE11 (but in Chrome).  Here is some relevant code in the directive:

```
public  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createPopover();
}

@HostBinding('class.visible') private visible: boolean;

@HostListener('mouseenter')
onMouseEnter(): void {
    debugger;
    this.visible = true;
    this.detectElementInViewport();
}

public createPopover(): void {
    this.popover = this.renderer.createElement("div");
    this.popover.innerHTML = this.config.text;
    this.popover.className += 'popover-content';

    //if config as a position set it, otherwise default it to top
    if(this.config.position) {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, this.config.position);
    } else {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'top');
    }

    //add popover container class for styling purposes
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'popover-container');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.popover);
}
```

The research I've done has said that the following lines in polyfills.ts are important to IE, and as you can see from this paste they're uncommented.  I've also done the recommended install of classlist.js.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/weak-map";
import "core-js/es6/set";

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import "classlist.js";  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import "core-js/es6/reflect";
```

One more thing I'll include is the generated HTML from dev tools in both browsers.  It looks identical except for the order of the attributes on the elements:

```
<!-- Chrome -->

<help-text _ngcontent-c11="" _nghost-c12="" ng-reflect-question="[object Object]" ng-reflect-position="top">
    <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "<p>Here is a help text</p>"
}-->
    <div _ngcontent-c12="" class="float-right">
        <svg-icon _ngcontent-c12="" icon="icon-info" ng-reflect-icon="icon-info" ng-reflect-config="[object Object]" class="top popover-container">
            <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><svg class="icon" focusable="false">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-info"></use>
            </svg><div _ngcontent-c12="" class="popover-content">
                <p>Here is a help text</p>
            </div>
        </svg-icon>
    </div>
</help-text>

<!-- IE -->

<help-text _ngcontent-c11="" _nghost-c12="" ng-reflect-question="[object Object]" ng-reflect-position="top">
    <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "<p>Here is a help text</p>"
}-->
    <div class="float-right" _ngcontent-c12="">
        <svg-icon class="top popover-container" icon="icon-info" ng-reflect-icon="icon-info" _ngcontent-c12="" ng-reflect-config="[object Object]">
            <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" focusable="false">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-info" />
            </svg><div class="popover-content" _ngcontent-c12="">
                <p>Here is a help text</p>
            </div>
        </svg-icon>
    </div>
</help-text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the polyfills, seems IE just still can't handle dealing with SVG stuff.  Moved directive to a surrounding div.  It messes up the style ever so slightly, but hopefully won't be a deal-breaker.

Old:

```
<div class="float-right" *ngIf="question.helpText">
    <svg-icon icon="icon-info" [popover]="{ text: question.helpText, position: position }"></svg-icon>
</div>
```

New:

```
<div class="float-right no-margin no-padding" *ngIf="question.helpText" [popover]="{ text: question.helpText, position: position }">
    <svg-icon icon="icon-info"></svg-icon>
</div>
```